Вопрос про составное именое сказуемое
Сценарий этого фильма был написан  известным писателем.
Что здесь сказуемое? Был написан или был написан писателем или был написан известным писателем. Если бы было такое же приложение но без слова быть, то где сказуемое? Слово быть это глагол связка, а именая часть может быть выражена одим словом?

Существуют два варианта предложения:
(1) Сценарий этого фильма написан известным писателем.
Важен факт написания, то есть результат действия в настоящий момент.
Сказуемое составное именное: написан. Связка быть пропущена, именная часть выражена кратким страдательным причастием.
(2) Сценарий этого фильма был написан известным писателем.
Важна законченность действия к определенному моменту в прошлом. К примеру, в дальнейшем в него могли вноситься изменения.
Сказуемое составное именное: был написан. Связка был, именная часть выражена кратким страдательным причастием.
Но здесь оба варианта предложения возможны.
Написан /был написан (кем?) писателем. Писателем (каким?) известным. Это дополнение и определение.
